# Convert rank and partition query to SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I would like to convert the following query to SqlAlchemy, but the documentation isn't very helpful:

```
select * from (
select *, 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date desc) AS RNK 
from table1
) d
where RNK = 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

use [`over`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over) expression

```
from sqlalchemy import func

subquery = db.session.query(
    table1,
    func.rank().over(
        order_by=table1.c.date.desc(),
        partition_by=table1.c.id
    ).label('rnk')
).subquery()

query = db.session.query(subquery).filter(
    subquery.c.rnk==1
)
```