# How to get top n results per group from a pool of ids in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables. The 1st represent one `article` per *row* and the 2nd represent one `news_cluster` per *row* (with an *array* column for all `articles_id` per *cluster*).

I need to get the 19 best `news_cluster` and then get the 4 best *articles* for each `news_cluster` (order by `l_score column`).

Currently I'm fetching all `articles_id` from all 19 `news_cluster` with SQLAlchemy and then I sort them by `news_cluster` and `l_score` with python :

```
all_news_obj = News.query.order_by(score).limit(19)
all_ids = sum([a_news.articles_id for a_news in all_news_obj], [])
all_articles = Articles.query.filter(Articles.id.in_(all_ids)).all()
articles_sorted = 4_best_l_score_sorted_by_cluster(all_articles)
```

I was wondering if there was a faster way to fetch and sort these articles and I saw that you can *group* by cluster (`news_id`) and get the top 4 `l_score` for each *group* with this psql query:

```sql
SELECT ranked.* FROM 
(SELECT articles.*, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY news_id ORDER BY l_score DESC)
    FROM articles
    WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[209146, 209140, 209154...])
) ranked
WHERE rank <=4
```

So it might be faster if psql handle the sorting in the first place but I have no clue how to implement this query in SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My question is mostly answered here : [Convert rank and partition query to SqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635099/convert-rank-and-partition-query-to-sqlalchemy)

I just needed to adapt it to my `Articles` model and add a filter to match the ids in `all_ids_array` :

```
subquery = db.session.query(
    Articles,
    func.rank().over(
        order_by=Articles.l_score.desc(),
        partition_by=Articles.news_id
    ).label('rank')
).filter(Articles.id.in_(all_ids_array)).subquery()

articles_sorted = db.session.query(subquery).filter(subquery.c.rank <= 4)
```

I'm a happy man : It's 0.1 second faster than fetching all articles and sorting them afterward with python.

Comment: Note that `articles_sorted` will consist of `Row` objects vs `Articles` ORM objects, which may be inconvenient depending on use case (for example, if you then want to call a model method on each returned instance).