# Extracting the first entry in each group using ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to extract the first entry in each group using the SqlAlchemy ORM, but struggle with the construct of this:

Example: Extract the first ever ordered item of each customer:

```
customer | date     | item
------------------------
Joe      | 20190101 | duck
Jane     | 20190101 | rabbit
Joe      | 20190202 | table
Bob      | 20190301 | guitar
Jane     | 20190301 | guitar
```

expected output

```
customer | date     | item
------------------------
Joe      | 20190101 | duck
Jane     | 20190101 | rabbit
Bob      | 20190301 | guitar
```

The problem is solved easily enough for pandas

```
df.sort_values(['date'],ascending=True).groupby('customer').first().reset_index()
# -- or --
df.groupby(["customer"]).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(["date"], ascending = True)).first().reset_index()
```

but i cannot find out how to achieve similar for SqlAlchemy 
(or for SQL for what it matters, as I struggle to understand the syntax and use of these Partition-Over functions).

Thanks for any help

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Does it really matter when using sqlalchemy? But, it's postgres-10.

Comment: OKay, at least for the SQL part i found out the wanted query: '''SELECT customer, date, 
        first_value(item) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY date ASC as first_item
        FROM table0;''', so now how to put this into sqlalchemy code

Comment: It does; for example with Postgresql you can use the `DISTINCT ON ... ORDER BY` idiom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069023/sqlalchemy-show-only-latest-result-if-a-join-returns-multiple-results, and if you want to use window functions, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635099/convert-rank-and-partition-query-to-sqlalchemy