# Limit results from a Python SQLAlchemy query to the top results from a subgroup

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, lateral-join

I have the following tables:

```
User
   id
   name

Points
   id
   user_id
   total_points(int)
```

user_id is the foreign key on the user table.
In the points table, each user can have multiple entries, for instance:

```
user A - 1000
user B - 1500
user A - 1250
User C - 3000
User A - 500
etc...
```

What I want to get is the top 3 results (total_points) from each user in the points table.

I can get all the entries on this table by doing this:

`db.session.query(Points).all()`

I can also get the result ordered by player:

`db.session.query(Points).order_by(Points.user_id).all()`

Then I can get the result ordered by highest to lowest points:

`db.session.query(Points).order_by(Points.user_id).order_by(Points.total_points.desc()).all()`

Now, I'm trying to get ONLY the top 3 total_points for EACH user. I'm trying to use the lateral clause but it's not working maybe because I'm not 100% sure how to use it.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
subquery = db.session.query(User.name, Points.total_points).join(Points, Points.user_id == User.id).filter(User.id == Points.user_id).order_by(Points.user_id).order_by(Points.total_points.desc()).limit(3).subquery().lateral('top 3')

db.session.query(User.name, Points.total_points).select_from(Points).join(subquery, db.true()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a function called `rank()`
Here is a easy example from [Postgresql doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html)

```
SELECT depname, empno, salary,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC)
FROM empsalary;
```

```
 depname  | empno | salary | rank 
-----------+-------+--------+------
 develop   |     8 |   6000 |    1
 develop   |    10 |   5200 |    2
 develop   |    11 |   5200 |    2
 develop   |     9 |   4500 |    4
 develop   |     7 |   4200 |    5
 personnel |     2 |   3900 |    1
 personnel |     5 |   3500 |    2
 sales     |     1 |   5000 |    1
 sales     |     4 |   4800 |    2
 sales     |     3 |   4800 |    2
(10 rows)
```

Here is some examples from another question on using [sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635099/convert-rank-and-partition-query-to-sqlalchemy)

```
subquery = db.session.query(
    table1,
    func.rank().over(
        order_by=table1.c.date.desc(),
        partition_by=table1.c.id
    ).label('rnk')
).subquery()
```